# how to connect two linux pcs from different network via cross cable?

Tags: linux, networking

I have two Linux PCs and  each on has a different IP and  I wand to connect them via cross cable. What the steps I should follow them ?

Comment: Plug the cables into the back of each machine!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22835/how-to-network-two-ubuntu-computers-using-ethernet-without-a-router

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a crossover cable to connect two computers, the computers are not connected to a LAN network. In this case, you will need to configure static IP addresses for each computer.

You have to make sure that both computers have IP addresses that are on the same subnet. For example, if you give one computer an IP address of 10.30.1.1, then you should give the second computer an IP of 10.30.1.2.

If you used the above IP addresses, you should use a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. If you use an incorrect subnet mask, the connection will not work.

Lastly, the value for the default gateway should be the same on both machines. You can pick which IP address you want to use, but use it on both computers for the default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

You already said they are in different networks, shall I understand you can not ping just by connecting the cable because the network segment/netmask are different?

1-EDIT I thought you were talking about Linux, but it's pretty similar: 
If that is the case to keep them connected I assume you have an extra network card on each PC. just need to [assign ip addresses on them](http://www.adminschoice.com/solaris-network-configuration), let say:

**PC1**

ethxx

10.0.100.12/24

**PC2**

ethyy

10.0.100.11/24

2-If you have only one network car per machine the you need to use [virtual network interfaces](http://solaris-x86.org/documents/guides/interfaces.mhtml), then you can remove the network cable and put your cross connection cable.

If you do that you should be able to ping only by connecting the cable.

May be with more details I can give more detailed information.

Comment: thanks, please how to create virtual network interface on solaris 10

Comment: before continuing. do you have two network cards on each computer or only one?

Comment: One with one card and another with two cards

Comment: Well on the machine with 2 NICs you can use the first method. O the other one you can use the second or just configure the network card to have an IP on the same range as the other-one. The problem with the second one is that you can only be connected to one physical network at the time.